# MagicalRecord: DeadLock in [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock]

Tags: core-data, magicalrecord

I'm doing the following - but my app freezes when fetching the object:

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    MyObject *myObject = [localContext objectWithID:objectID];
}];
```

I found some blogs mentioning dead locks with FetchRequests and nested contexts; but what can I do as an alternative here?

Thanks a lot,

Stefan

Comment: Still having problems? Could you post more of the method? Where does this objectID come from?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that use `MR_inContext:` on the object whose id is objectID. So something like this:

```
MyObject *myObject = [getMeAnObject];  
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    MyObject *myObjectLocal = [myObject MR_inContext:localContext];  
}];
```